# How to align lines with consistency?

Tags: formatting, alignment

For example, if I paste this UserScript Meta **perfectly aligned** here on *stackoverflow.com* in *Notepad++*, I get something [**badly aligned**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoO6Q.png).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Example
// @description     This is an example
// @include         https://www.example.com/*
// @grant           none
// @version         0.1
// @author          user
// ==/UserScript==
```

Is there anything I can do to ensure consistency of alignement ?

I tried to play with both <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> keys, without success.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts when you use tabs. Depending on configuration, the tab size can be 2/4/8/x characters and this setting may differ on different websites and in different programs.

If you want the snippet to look exactly the same everywhere, you have to use spaces, because space is always 1 character.

Also, [StackOverflow advises](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you should use spaces here:

> Also, don't use tabs – they may look good in your editor, but they'll just make a mess on Stack Overflow.

EDIT: But (according to your screenshot) in your case the problem is that you are using a font that is not monospaced. **You need to use a monospace font**, which means that every character has the same width. Monospace fonts for example: Courier New, Inconsolata.

Comment: I've just aligned all the lines in the header here with space only, then when pasting it in Notepad++ still get something different/unaligned.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is that you are using a font that is not monospaced. Select a monospace font, like Courier New or Inconsolata.

Comment: Indeed, the font I use is the issue. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Glad to help :)